# Datatables get row data and then do fn.dataTable.ext.search.push

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, filter, datatables

My alert is working but I don't know how to use the rowData to filter my other datatables instances.
Here's my codepen: http://codepen.io/smuglovsky/pen/YpNjXm?editors=1010

I learned how to "click on each row and get the data" here: https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html

I also found how to "get the data from a row that was clicked upon" here: https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector

I know I'm almost there, but I'm stuck on line 460 of my codepen:

```
  $('#example-sections tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var data = table_sections.row(this).data();
    var rowData = table_sections.row(this).data();
    // ... do something with rowData
    alert('You clicked on ' + data[0] + '\'s row');
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
      function(settings, data, rows, dataIndex, rowIndex, rowData) {
        // I want to filter the rowData, just like the alert is doing
        return data[0] == +data[0] ? true : false;
      }
    );
    table_main.draw();
    table_books.draw();
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So using "$.fn.dataTable.ext.search" adds a search custom function to ALL data table instances.  What I think you want here is to filter other DataTable instances using the value from a particular grid row click. If so you would want to approach this problem a little differently.

The following solution assumes that the first column of your "example-sections" grid corresponds to the column you want to search on your "table_main" and "table_books" columns.  If so you can merely get the column for "table_main" and "table_books" using the index and apply the search to it using the data from row you clicked on.

```
$('#example-sections tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  var rowData = table_sections.row(this).data();
  // ... do something with rowData
  alert('You clicked on ' + rowData[0] + '\'s row');

  // Lets build a regular expression that will give only exact matches.
  var searchRegExp = new RegExp("^" + rowData[0] + "$");

  // Ok so we are going to use a regex.  Second param is to turn on
  // search by a regular expression.  The third param is to turn off "smart"
  // searching which would conflict.  The last param is to turn off case 
  // insensitive matching.
  table_main.column(0).search(searchRegExp, true, false, false).draw();
  table_books.column(0).search(searchRegExp, true, false, false).draw();
});
```

NOTE:  For "table_main.column(0)" the "0" is the index of the column in the data set so if you have hidden columns those count towards this index. For example lets say my first visible column is an "ID" column but I have TWO hidden columns that are defined within my "columns" definition before the "ID" column then the index of the "ID" column would be "2" not "0".

EDIT:  changed search to only return exact match.  Reference:  https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()

Comment: Thank you very much Aliester! It works very nicely. I have a question: It filters all the red 1's, but I'm getting also the red 1's like 11, 12, 21, etc. I'm gonna need an "exact match".

I added underscores like this "_1_". I tried "<1>" but apparently datatables doesn't like these.

My codepen doesn't work at the moment because http://crossorigin.me/ is down. I've tried fiddle, plunkr & jsbin with no success. Can think of another cors? :) In the meantime, please have a look here: http://solidarityfarm.tk/AdminLTE-master/pages/layout/_______o_tE_029.html

Again, thanks so much buddy!

Comment: @user2792945  I think by default it does a "LIKE" type search instead of exact match.  Let me see if I can figure that out.

Comment: @user2792945  Try the updated code above.  I think that will workout.

Comment: Awesome! I was gonna add the underscores to sections, books, chapters & verses, and considering the Bible has 31,102 verses, looking at my excel file, you just reduced my data by pretty much 250,000 characters... Thanks again Aliester :)

Comment: @user2792945  no problem glad I could help

Comment: The regex is not working for some reason. But https://crossorigin.me is up again, although pretty slow. I disabled table_main and the other ones (since we know they all get updated :) So I just left the two with the red & yellow, which should load for you fine. Same codepen, JS panel, line 483: http://codepen.io/smuglovsky/pen/YpNjXm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128659/discussion-between-aliester-and-user2792945).